# Click event stops working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish someone could help me, I'm a little bit irked about this problem since I've been resolving other issues with this scroll behavior that I'm trying to implement on this [site](http://altivamedia.com/pruebas/romulos/wp/menu/)...  as you see my sub-menu (on the left) follows the window position as you scroll or you can click any option on the sub-menu wich will trigger an animation, well what seems to be the problem is that everytime I click a second time it won't work, until I re-click it, it will work...

Here's my code

Variables

```
var startDistance = 210;
var $scrollingDiv = $("#sub-menu");
var position = $("#footer").position();
var height = $("#sub-menu").height();
var pos = position.top - (height + 460);
```

This is to differ between users and animation scroll

```
$("body,html").bind("scroll mousedown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup", function(e){
            if ( e.which > 0 || e.type === "mousedown" || e.type === "mousewheel"){
                 if($(window).scrollTop() > startDistance && $(window).scrollTop() < pos) {

                    $scrollingDiv.stop().animate({
                        paddingTop: ($(window).scrollTop() - 75) + "px"
                    }, 'slow');

                }
                if($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
                    $scrollingDiv.stop().animate({
                        paddingTop: 0
                    }, 'slow');
                }
            }
     });
```

Click behavior

```
$("#sub-menu ul li a").live('click', function(ev) {
            var $anchor = $(this);
            console.log($anchor.attr('href'));
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
            }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo', function() {
                $scrollingDiv.stop().animate({
                    paddingTop: ($($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 556) + "px"
                }, 'slow');
            });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

It might be the silliest thing but I've been watching my screen for last hour w/o being able to realize what's going on.

Edit: I'm posting my scroll code behavior too because I feel that It might be a global problem and not only related to my click code

Thank you in advance!

Comment: .live has been deprecated as of jQuery 1.7, you're using 1.8.3, you should use .on instead.

Comment: try changing all instances of stop() to stop(true,true) and see if it resolves the issue. Stop makes the animation stop exactly where it was when stop was called. However stop(true,true) empties the animation queue and will instantly finish the animation that was in progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[22:00:25.137] ReferenceError: event is not defined @ http://altivamedia.com/pruebas/romulos/wp/wp-content/themes/romulos/_/js/functions.js:45
```

You've accidentally wrote `event` instead of `ev`:

```
        });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Since `event` hasn't been defined a `ReferenceError` gets thrown. Simply use the correct variable:

```
        });
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

#### Remark

In order to find such errors on your own use your browser's error console.

Comment: I missed that the first time. Don't know if that was all of the problem but good catch. +1

Comment: thank you :D, althought that wasn't the problem, I was dumb not to realize I had mousedown on body behaviors that's why my click worked wrong I guess all I needed was a break thanks thought! :)